# What does Failure of Web server exactly mean?

Tags: networking, server, web, fault, ddos

What really happens when the web server fails ? I know the usual thing that the Website will be down and the page I have requested is inaccessible.

The cause might be external like too many incoming requests but what really happens in the inner workings of the server that leads to such a condition ?

Answer (score 0):

I might be congestion due to lack of bandwidth or the VM/server that is containing the info/web page